# Matlab - surf and contour3, clipping order?

Tags: matlab, contour, surface

I am plotting data as a surface in matlab.  I have three data matrices, `x,y,z.`  The values of z may not be outside the range 0~1.

I generate plots with the following:

```
surf(x,y,z);
[c,h] = contour3(x,y,z,'LevelList',[0 : 0.1 : 1],'Color','k');
clabel(c,h,[0 : 0.1 : 1]);
```

I also do some modifications to the surface, such as setting `shading interp`.

[image]

As you can see, the result image clips the contours with the underlying surface.  How can I ensure that the contour and labels are plotted above the surface?

Comment: add a small extra bit to `z` in the contour plot, 0.005 might be enough.

Comment: @David This solution does not work when the plot is viewed from other perspectives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some digging in the doc, I have found the best solution.

The clipping order is specified at the `axes` level.

A complete MWE to have the contours always on top of the surface is below:

```
fig = figure;
ax = get(gca);
ax.SortMethod = 'childorder'; % this is the important line
surf(x,y,z);
[c,h] = contour3(x,y,z,'LevelList',[0 : 0.1 : 1],'Color','k');
clabel(c,h,[0 : 0.1 : 1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try working on the properties of the `contour` patches: increase the `linewidth` of the patch' edge: the default value is 0.5: a `linewidth` of 1 or 1.5 should be enough.

On the same way you can set the properties of the lavels generated by `clabel`: you can set the `font size` and `font weight` to make them more visible. Also you can set the number of label to be added by specifying the `labelspacing` property.

An interesting option could also be to manually set the labels: this can be done by specifying the `manaul` property in the `clabel` call.

In the following you find an example based on the `peaks` surface:

```
[x,y,z]=peaks
surf(x,y,z);
shading interp
hold on
[c,h] = contour3(x,y,z,[-10:1:10]);
set(h(:),'linewidth',1,'edgecolor','k')
clabel(c,h,[-10:1:10],'fontsize',9,'fontweight','bold','rotation',0,'labelspacing',99);
% clabel(c,h,'manual','fontsize',9,'fontweight','bold','rotation',0);
```

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps.